# ¿por que mi arreglo pasa nulo cuando lo envio desde javascript por axios hacia la vista?

Tags: laravel, axios

Cuando envió un arreglo con una serie de datos desde javascript por axis hacia una vista en laravel me sale el mensaje que fue exitoso el envió, pero en la vista cuando imprimo ese arreglo, este aparece null, y yo miro ese arreglo en js y si estoy enviando información.

Aca mi codigo.

```
/* Este es mi funcion javascript */
function addingToShoppingCar() {

    var image = localStorage.getItem("imagen");
    var names = localStorage.getItem("nameless");
    var descrip = localStorage.getItem("descript");
    var totalVal = localStorage.getItem("totalProduct");
    var totalUn = localStorage.getItem("totalUnits");
    var valueNew = localStorage.getItem("newValue");
    var unitsNew = localStorage.getItem("newUnits");

    var arraySale = [];
    arraySale.push(image);
    arraySale.push(names);
    arraySale.push(descrip);
    arraySale.push(totalVal);
    arraySale.push(totalUn);
    arraySale.push(valueNew);
    arraySale.push(unitsNew);

    console.log(arraySale);

    axios.get('/CreateServiceOutLogin', {
            params: {
                'arraySale': arraySale
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
            if (res.status == 200) {
                console.log("La data fue enviada con exito!!");
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        })
} 

/* La ruta */
Route::get('/CreateServiceOutLogin', 'web\serviceController@index')->name('CreateServiceOutLogin');

/* El controlador */
public function  index(Request $request) {

$arrayData = $request->arraySale;

}
```

Alguien me podria indicar que estoy haciendo mal, por favor.

Comment: en que momento cargas los datos al localstorage? ya que solo veo `get` pero no `set` deberias validar que existan esos elementos en el localstorage: `for ( let x of ["imagen","nameless","descript","totalProduct","totalUnits","newValue","newUnits"])
     if(!localStorage.getItem(x))
      console.log(`no existe ${x} en el localstorge`)

Comment: Yo lo que me pregunto es ¿porqué usar el verbo 'GET' (*obtener*) para *enviar* datos? ¿Qué pasa con 'POST'?